# How to Connect to a web service (SSL enabled and proxy interface)

Tags: java, .net, web-services

There is a web service running on tomcat on a server. It is built on Java Servlet. It is listening others to call itself on a SSL enabled http port. so its web service adreess looks
like: https://172.29.12.12/axis/services/XYZClient?wsdl

On the other hand I want to connect the web service above from a windows application which is built on .NET frame work.

Finally, when I want to connect the web service from my computer; I get some specific erros;

Firstly I get; Proxy authentication error; then I added some new line to my code;

```
   Dim cr As System.Net.NetworkCredential = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("xname", "xsurname", "xdomainname")
        Dim myProxy As New WebProxy("http://mar.xxxyyy.com", True)
        myProxy.Credentials = cr
```

Secondly, after this modifications It says that bad request.
I did not get over  this error.

Moreover I did try to connect the web server on the same computer. I copied my executable program to the computer where the web service runs. The error was like;

> The underlying connection was closed:
>   Could not establish trust relationship
>   for SSL/TLS secure channel

PS: When I try to connect to web service by using Internet Explorer; I see firstly some warnings about accepting an unknown certificate and I click take me to web service an I get there clearly.

I want to know what are the basic elements to connect a web service, could you please tell me the requirements that I have to use on my windows project.

regards bk

Comment: Now, I get
The remote server returned an error 504 Gateway Timeout

still problemss...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://my.execpc.com/~gopalan/dotnet/webservices/webservice_csharp_client.html) offers a simple step-by-step guide on building a web service client with C#.NET.

Step 5 on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649205.aspx) shows how to add a certificate to your trusted store and Step 6 is another way to build a very simple web service client in C#.NET.